# FormsAuthentication not redirecting after validating user in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Forms `Auhtentication in MVC4`, my problem is that users are not redirect from login page after authentication.

Below is my Login Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
      {
         FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName,model.RememberMe);
         RedirectToDefault(returnUrl,model.UserName);
      }
      else
      {
         this.ShowMessage(MessageType.Danger, "Invalid username or password.");
      }
   }

   this.ShowMessage(MessageType.Danger, "Invalid username or password.");
   return View(model);
}
```

and my Web.Config :

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

This code :

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName,model.RememberMe);
RedirectToDefault(returnUrl, model.UserName);
```

are executed but the code still got the last Return View(model);

Please any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You saying its not redirecting you *from* the auth page *to* another? Like the index page??

Comment: Yes, even when username and password are correct that is Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password) return true.

Comment: Why not, instead of `RedirectToDefault`, use `RedirectToAction` and point it toward your index page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I have called a PartialView on the home page. The Controller where I have the PatialView Result was decorated with [Authorize] Attribute.

All I did was that I decorated the Partiview Result with [AllowAnonymous] and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

These are my assumptions on your issue.

Does your `Login` is separate view in your project or partial?

1. Make Sure your `Login` view is not partial View at Form Post.
2. Make Sure your `Login` view is not having any `Syntax Error in HTML/Code Errors`.
3. Make sure your view properly included in Solution of a project.
4. Have you passed correct model in your `Action Result`?
5. Do you have a code to specify the `LoginModel` in your view?

**Solution to Identify the Issue:**

To Identify the Issue Just Add this in your `Global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{// Keep Debugger Here
     Exception exception = Server.GetLastError(); 
     Response.Clear(); // Just check the exception variable hint in Quick Watch
}
```

Comment: am suprise if i use thiss code  if (model.UserName == "mark" && model.Password == "test")
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            } it worked fine

Comment: Yes the Mistake is you `Returned the Same view name with Same Model` in your `ActionResult`.